# Como desencriptar una contraseña

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, he avanzado en mi formulario para modificar las contraseñas.
Ahora necesito tambien que como medida de seguridad adicional para poder modificar la contraseña debe introducirse la anterior.
Para ello, hice una primera prueba creando este miniformulario:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="clave" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Antigüa Contraseña</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="clave" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('campo') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="campo" value="{{decrypt(auth()->user()->password)}}" required>

        @if ($errors->has('campo'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('campo') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Esto pide al usuario su actual contraseña. Como se que hay un sistema de encriptamiento, he hecho que al cargar el formulario ya se muestre en la caja la actual contraseña desencriptada, como primer paso para vez que sale todo bien.
Por desgracia, me encuentro con esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que esta saliendo mal?

Comment: Prueba a no mostrar la actual contraseña. Puede ser un problema de seguridad

Comment: No debes hacer eso. Yo lo que haría es pedir la contraseña actual y encriptarla con el mismo método que la que tienes almacenada. Tras eso, tienes que comparar la contraseña insertada por el usuario y encriptada, con la que ya había almacenada encriptada. Si ha introducido la misma, dará como resultado positivo en la comparación.

Comment: Para empezar las contraseñas de laravel no se desencryptan, el algoritmo utilizado por laravel no repite la contraseña encryptada, es decir si dos usuarios tienen la misma contraseña esto no se vera reflejado en la base de datos, y por ultimo te recomiendo leer https://styde.net/cambiar-contrasena-con-laravel-validando-clave-actual/ para ver como se hace el cambio de password.